# A PDF viewer for PDF with large vector images on linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, imageview, vector-graphics, viewer

I need to view some PDF with large vector images (they can be really large) on linux (I am on Debian Wheesy). I need also to zoom on theses images with more than 400% (infinite zoom would be great, more than 800% would be good). I have tested several PDF viewers but they have the following problems :

Evince : cannot zoom more than four or five increase of zoom ("+"), the image is so big that it doesn't even display the percentage of zoom.

Okular : cannot display the image (all is blank) after a certain degree of zoom (~70%-80%).

muPDF (last version from git and debian repository version) : cannot open a too large image. Error message : "Interger overflow" (last version) or "Out of memory" (debian version).

Xara LX : cannot import PDF in the open source version. Convert PDF to SVG for importing into Xara LX does not fit my needs because my PDF contains several pages.

Inkscape : can open PDF and its zoom is powerful, but it's not a PDF viewer so the navigation is slow.

Xournal : cannot open correctly the image (all is black).

Do you know others open source PDF viewer that could open and zoom on PDF with large vector images ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: try Foxit-Reader: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/

Comment: Too bad it's not open source.

Comment: A hint for Okular is that if you refresh the page at larger zooms (F5 key) then it will redraw and you will see the image.

Comment: Evince by default has quite a small cache, resulting in a fairly low maximum zoom. Increasing this cache can result in much higher zoom percentages on large documents. See this article (specifically the `gsettings` commands) for info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/721217

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1011336/173666

Answer (score 12):

Both Ubuntu's [Evince](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/721217) reader and Linux Mint's [Xreader](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/issues/166) will increase their max level of zoom if their cache size is increased. You can use `gsettings` to view or change these settings.

Evince reader's zoom can be increased with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince page-cache-size 200
```

Xreader with:

```
gsettings set org.x.reader page-cache-size 200
```

In both cases you'll need to select an appropriate cache size in megabytes. You can first look at what your current setting's value is by instead using the `gsettings get` command.

Answer (score 3):

xpdf is the open-source viewer that works efficiently on very large vector images.
The only drawback is that it has an old interface and is not well integrated into gnome; I have to start it from the commandline as it doesn't show up in my Nautilus "open with" list.

Answer (score 1):

[qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview)

For example Evince failed in opening the map (size is 197MB) attached to this paper

[EVANS, David JA; EWERTOWSKI, Marek; ORTON, Chris. Eiríksjökull plateau icefield landsystem, Iceland. Journal of Maps, 2016, 12.5: 747-756.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/17445647.2015.1072448)

on the other hand qpdfview succeded (but no more of 500% zoom).

Answer (score 0):

Try Foxit-Reader: http://foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux

Only drawback is not being open-source but it works just fine.